# Can't find a path for resource in a Coca Touch Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, frameworks, ios8

I am using the new Coca Touch Framework for iOS 8.0+

I am trying to get a path for resource using the regular [NSBundle mainBundle] nad it doens't work. Anyone knows whats going on??

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"my_text_file" ofType:@"txt"];
```

Back when I was using regular static library it found it.
I just throw the file inside the Framework / Static Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frameworks does load into your bundle.
I found you only need to make a simple adaptation.

Let's say your framework is FWork.
Simply put this prefix

> Frameworks/FWork/

before the resource, like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Frameworks/FWork/my_text_file" ofType:@"txt"];
```

and it will be found.